# Перенос слова "оформленное"

Tags: перенос

Какой вариант переноса слова "оформленное" правильный? "оформ-ленное" или "офор-мленное"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил оформ-
ленное, поскольку тогда морфема не разрывается.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы ни чудилось второе, все же первый вариант: оформ-ленное.